# Returning the method of a function

Tags: javascript, inheritance

In the code below, I've got two objects declared, with one object inheriting the properties and functions of another.

I want to use the `super` variable to call the methods of the object I inherited from. When I trace out `itemEditor`, I can see the function and it's methods correctly.  When I try to access the method of `itemEditor`, it returns `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong? Is there a better way to do this?

```
var myObject = {    
itemEditor : function (vars) {

    this.editItem = function () {
        alert("Editing Item");
    }
},

recurringItemEditor : function (vars) {
    myObject .itemEditor.apply(this, [vars]);
    this.prototype = myObject.itemEditor.prototype;
    var super = myObject.itemEditor

    this.editItem = function () {
        console.log("fn.recurringItemEditor.editItem");
        console.log(super);
        console.log(super.editItem);
        super.editItem.call(this);
    }
}
```

Comment: It is exactly code like this that gives JavaScript a bad name. Simply because JS allows you to do runtime injections, it does not mean that the code has to be deliberately designed to make it difficult to read. I am sure there is an elegant way to accomplish what you are trying to do. Start with a clean sheet of paper.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems a little confused.  On the one hand myObject.itemEditor is a constructor and therefore a function (`myObject.itemEditor.apply(this, [vars])`), and on the other you treat it like an object with a prototype (`this.prototype = myObject.itemEditor.prototype;`).

That's not even considering that `super` is a reserved keyword.

Your example may be simplifying something you are trying to do, but I don't see why you don't just use the usual prototype inheritance.  That way you can still have a method in your local instance and call the prototype one within it if you want e.g.

```
recurringItemEditor : function (vars) {
    this.prototype = new myObject.itemEditor(vars);

    this.editItem = function () {
        console.log("fn.recurringItemEditor.editItem");
        console.log(this.prototype);
        console.log(this.prototype.editItem);
        this.prototype.editItem.call(this);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used your advice and it works well now.  In regards to treating it like a function and an object, `myObject .itemEditor.apply(this, [vars]);` was still required in order for the object to inherit the properties of itemEditor.  I should have made that clear in the original code.  If there's a better way to do this, let me know.

```
var myObject = {    
    itemEditor : function (vars) {
        var myVars = vars + "foo";

        this.editItem = function () {
            alert(myVars);
        }
    },

    recurringItemEditor : function (vars) {
        myObject .itemEditor.apply(this, [vars]);
        this.prototype = new myObject.itemEditor(vars);

        this.editItem = function () {
            console.log("fn.recurringItemEditor.editItem");
            console.log(this.prototype);
            console.log(this.prototype.editItem);
            this.prototype.editItem.call(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: With myObject.itemEditor as a prototype of a recurringItemEditor object, all the prototype properties should be available as if were on the object.  That's what prototype inheritance does.  For your current example I don't see why you need the `myObject .itemEditor.apply(this, [vars]);`. But your code looks much more like common modern Javascript now.  Accept my answer? :)